# How to handle Oracle SQLcl syntax errors?

Tags: database, bash, oracle, sqlcl

I'm using Jenkins for CI/CD Oracle PL/SQL scripts using Oracle SQLcl, so i want to catch syntax errors for Jenkins Pipeline, for example:

```
SQL> seelect * from emp;

Error que empieza en la línea: 1 del comando :
seelect * from emp
Informe de error -
Comando desconocido
```

How can I end connection to database with a sh/bash error code when a syntax error is detected?

NOTE: I use WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE to ORA-XXX errors, but i can't catch syntax errors.

Thank You

Comment: Syntax errors are basically the interpreter *I give up, I do not know what you want*. You cannot catch them because the interpreter does not know to do so. In case it is simple: you misspelled **Select**, just 1 *E*.

Comment: So if I have a huge PL / SQL script and it has a syntax error, is there no way to make the connection terminate with an error code? Or just the database doesn't run the script?

Answer (score 0):

Ive used this before in a jenkins pipe:

```
 stage('Check Logs') {
    steps {
      script {
        if (manager.logContains('.*ORA-.*')) {
          error("Build failed due to ORA Errors")
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as OP mentions, syntax errors don't have an ORA- number with them.

Comment: then look for the syntax of a syntax error

the point of the code block isnt that its only looking for ORA but it can be used to look for any string pattern and fail the pipe.